# Is expression completion in typescript block scoped?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

The handbook has this example:

```
 let fullName: string = `Bob Bobbington`;
 let sentence: string = `Hello, my name is ${fullName}.
```

How does typescript go about resolving `fullName`.  Does it have to be in the same block scope as the template string?

Comment: The variable needs to be accessible in that scope, just like with any other statement, i.e.: `console.log(fullName);`

Comment: It's the same as how regular string interpolated variables are resolved...

Comment: Are you asking how does template string resolves `${fullName}`?

Comment: OK so it does not need to be in the same scope as long as it is accessible.  Makes sense.  Thanks.